# Insert overrides default null

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Create a table with `TEXT` column, which defaults to `NULL`

```
public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE ttt (k TEXT, v TEXT DEFAULT NULL)");
    }
}
```

Insert row, without specifying that `NULL`-defaulted column

```
SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
values.put("k", "1");
db.insertWithOnConflict("ttt", null, values, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);
```

Then execute `SELECT * FROM ttt WHERE v IS NULL` (I use Chrome Developers Tools, connecting to database via Stetho). Result is **nothing**, because `k` in just inserted row suddenly is not NULL though expecting it should be NULL.

If I insert row 'by hands', executing `INSERT OR IGNORE INTO ttt(k) VALUES ('2')`, and then repeat `SELECT * FROM ttt WHERE v IS NULL`, I get just second column (with `k = 2`), as expected.

Can anybody confirm this behaviour? Is this a bug in Android SDK?

**P.S.** Have tried adding

```
values.putNull("v");
```

but it did not help :(